# Add superscripts and subscripts to plotreg variable labels

Tags: r, label, expression, texreg

I'm wondering how to tweak `plotreg()`'s `gl()` function (it's function from the `texreg` package) to accommodate variables labels that contain super- or sub-scripts?

I've experimented with `expression()` and `paste()` but to no avail. I provide a working example (from [their documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/texreg/versions/1.37.5/topics/plotreg)) at below:

```css
# install.packages("texreg")
library(texreg)

ctl <- c(4.17, 5.58, 5.18, 6.11, 4.50, 4.61, 5.17, 4.53, 5.33, 5.14)
trt <- c(4.81, 4.17, 4.41, 3.59, 5.87, 3.83, 6.03, 4.89, 4.32, 4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl", "Trt")) # need to tweak this part
# for example, Ctl^2, Trt[2]
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)
lm.D90 <- lm(weight ~ group - 1)
plotreg(lm.D9) # plot model output as a diagram
```

Comment: '[' is a metacharacter. I think you may be looking into a lot of trouble trying to change the behavior on this one.
Why not just create a customized function that inludes the super or subscripts as additional arguments?

Comment: Are you looking for these sub/super scripts to appear in your plot output? i.e. 'groupCtl^2" appears with a superscript not as written here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to change the axis labels with ggplot2.

```
library(ggplot2)

g <- plotreg(lm.D90)

labs <- c(expression(Ctl^2),expression(Trt[2]))

g <- g + scale_x_discrete(labels = labs)
```

[image: Ouput]

Comment: Many thanks, this is one neat solution. (Pardon me for my late reply. It appears that my earlier reply didn't show up in this thread, not sure what happened)